# Error al llenar Tabla html con JSON

Tags: json, mvc, bootstrap-table

Esta es mi tabla HTML

```
<div class="modal-body"> <!--EMPIEZA BODY DEL MODAL -->
                             <div class="panel-body">
                                <table async="async" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th> # </th>
                                            <th> PART NUMBER </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="contenido">
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                        </div><!--TERMINA BODY DEL MODAL -->
```

Este es el JS, Abro un modal y lo lleno con un JSON

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');

    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
        $("#contenido")
    .append("<tr><td>" + value.Row + "</td><td>" + value.Row2+ "</td></tr>");
    });
```

Y este es el detalle:
https://ibb.co/d08EPd  (no pude cargar la imagen aqui), pero el detalle es que la tabla no me detecta los registros, no puedo mostrar 10 solamente por ejemplo, ni puedo cambiar de pagina cuando son mas de 10, no me marca los registros que hay, etc..

Comment: ¿Has puesto un breakpoint para confirmar que hay datos en el envío?

Comment: Si si hay datos, pero los pone abajo de la tabla bien raro, checa la imagen xD, solo muestra uno pero en la tabla dice que no hay registros